# Creating a very defined UV-map with uniform faces stretching across the complete texture image

Tags: texturing, uv

what I'm trying to do is to use an equirectangular image and texture it on selected faces of an UV-sphere. The image would be a satellite picture of the earth, for instance, with known bounds in terms of longitude and latitude.

My basic plan would be to lay out the UV-sphere in a way so that the texture image corresponds to a multiple of the faces horizontally and vertically. Then I want to create an UV-wrapping of the according faces. The UV-map would have to be distributed equally across the full texture image. The faces in the UV-map would be perfect rectangles.

That's the theory....

I'm already able to UV-unwrap a contiguous region of faces from the UV-sphere. I'm also getting my texture roughly where I want to have it. However, I'm struggling to modify the faces resp. vertices of the UV-map in a way so that they spread EXACTLY across my texture image while all faces are EXACTLY uniform. Though, I'm able to grab each vertex and move it roughly to where I need it. But with this method I cannot position them perfectly. So this can't be the way to go.

I added a screenshot that should illustrate to problem nicely, I believe....

So where's the trick here?

Thanks,
Mario

Update: Seems I found a solution. See the second screenshot attached. What I did is to select the horizontal edges and align them to the Y-axis so that they are in one row. I did this in my exemplary configuration four times. The outer edges I moved to the according edge of the texture. For the inner ones I edited the Y-coordinate manually to be 0.3333 resp. 0.6666. The same I did with the vertical edges, but aligning them to the X-axis end editing the x-coordinate of the inner three edges to be 0.25, 0.5, and 0.75 respectively.

I honestly do not know where these diagonal edges that are present now are coming from. Somehow there are also more vertices than before, and they are strangely coupled with the "actual" vertices. But as far as I can judge the situation these additional edges do not cause harm and the result is what it is supposed to be.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If I get you right you are asking for a better uv mapped sphere..? maybe [something like this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zzu28tdci7zimr4/plane2sphere.blend?dl=0) wich is usally done from curving a plane

Comment: @calambre Not really.... As shown in the screenshot, I took 4x3 faces and made an UV-unwrapping from them. What I got you can see in the UV-editor to the left. The 4x3 faces are placed in a way where Blender believes (I guess) there is a minimum distortion and it is also trying to maximize the use of the available texture. However, this cannot be used here. The faces in the UV editor must be rectangular and must be sized to exactly fit the texture (formally neither a single pixel too small, nor a single pixel too large).

Comment: ok, I see, but if you can generate the sphere from a plane, that plane could already have the right uv mapping... that was the idea, check that I updated the blend file: unwrap one plane, tile it using array modifier and then curve to sphere... it's just a way, you can fix the uvs in your example too, it would get a little more work maybe... or maybe I still don't get what you need :p

Comment: @calambre Aha, ok, I think I got your point. Might be possible as well, but probably overly complex. It seems I found a solution - check the update in my initial post. Btw., the reason why I'm doing this is to reduce the texturing to the area of interest. This allows to use a very-high resolution texture without blowing up the computer...

Comment: ok, now I understand what you wanted, to map just those 12 polygons... mapping with 'Reset' on one face and then 'Follow Active Quads' could have helped then, and scaling down by 1/3 or 1/4

Comment: Indeed, that seems to work as well. However, there was some additional hurdle with the rotation. When I UV-unwrap with "Reset" then I got the UV-map with each face on the image, but rotated by 90 degrees. The trick here seems that BEFORE applying "Follow Active Quads" I have to rotate the UV-map and then scale it to fit the texture image again. Then I apply "Follow Active Quads". Then I grab the UV-map and move it to the origin of the texture, then I scale X with 0.25 and Y with 0.3333, and finally I grab the UV-map again and move it to the origin of the texture image.

Comment: I thought you needed 4x3 patches 'all over' your sphere, that's why I went with a plane, sorry for that... if you used default Sphere object it already has good uvs, no need to unwrap, just scaling 4·Y and 32/3·X and use Constrain to Image Bounds later, many ways to do it, there must be some addons also, but at least you could solve it..!

Comment: No need to be sorry! Your trick with the Reset-mapping and Follow-Active-Quads works very well with an arbitrary number of faces. One thing that is probably a bit "hairy" is the selection of the faces. In my demo-example with these 4x3 faces it's rather simple. But I think that I have to divide the UV sphere with a resolution of 1 degree latitude and longitude for reasons of precision. So I end up with probably a few hundreds of faces I have to select in the UV sphere. But I believe that this is manageable.

Comment: you can click on a face and Ctlr+Shit+click on the diagonal / opposite face to select a patch of faces... also I find it strange you need that much resolution, but could try subdivision modifier: 45 faces across, with a 3 levels subdivision are 360 faces

Comment: The precision is a matter of the bounds of the texture and what I maybe have to cut off or use. Consider the texture spans at a longitude from say 23 west to 48 east - so in total 71 degrees. When I have a 1 degree resolution I can place the texture exactly where it should be. When I use a resolution of say 5 degrees, I would have to cut 3 degrees to the west (in order to get 20 degrees) and 3 degrees to the east in order to get 45 degrees. However, what would be possible as well is to fill up with empty data to the east and west instead. I'll have to see how I proceed here....